# Best IDE for android development for beginners

Tags: windows, android, java

What is the best IDE (integrated development environment) to use on a  64x based 1.6 GHz running windows 8 & 2gb RAM for android app development for beginners?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best option is the [Android App Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) **but** I would strongly recommend upgrading your development machine first, especially the RAM - "GB is very low for development work & Windows 8 will be using most of it.

APP Studio Recommendations:
Windows:

- Microsoft® Windows® 7/8/10 (32- or 64-bit)
- 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- 2 GB of available disk space minimum,
- 4 GB Recommended (500 MB for IDE + 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)
- 1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution

Upgrading RAM is normally reasonably simple and cheap.

The Android App Studio is a **Free**, gratis, download of size 927 MB for Windows so you will need a reasonable internet connection *and preferably not a capped or charged one*.

Comment: I think that 927 GB, should be 927MB? Android Studio is not THAT big :)